# SQL Server 2008R2 log filled and now database won't start

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

today I ran a big looping insert job that perhaps went wrong, in any case the transaction log filled the diskspace.  I cancelled the job.

I tried to make some more space by deleting a few old programs etc from that drive, but could only clear a hundred mb or so.

I then used SQL Server Management Studio to put the DB offline, with the idea that putting it offline, then on again would help clear the log.  But the offline dialog just hang there waiting.

So i've shutdown and restarted the server, with the idea it should recover.

Now when I use SQL Server Management Studio to log in to the DB server, its says "cannot open user default database" Login failed.

What can I do to get this up and running again?

Comment: This Q was put on hold, but I don't get how this is off-topic, its a specific MS SQL Server 2008R2 management question about a software project, not hardware related, and certainly not general software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get rid of the log file: detach the database, delete the log file from disk, attach database.

Edit: read [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/04/sql-server-fix-error-4064-cannot-open-user-default-database-login-failed-login-failed-for-user/) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b32c862a-799c-43c4-a731-c4811078c8bd/cannot-open-user-default-database-error-4064) to solve the login problem.

Comment: Your link did help, I got in to the master database.  Now I can see the DB I was working on is offline.  To get it online again, do I need to first fix up the transaction log problem?

Comment: If your disks are full, you will most likely run into your first problem again. So yes.